# Whay I'm getting error message "Wrong parameter attribute_code"

Tags: attributes, magento2

1. Go to Admin >> Stores >> Attributes >> Product select `price` or any other attributes
2. Make any/or no changes
3. Click "Save Attribute"
   Changes are not saved and get error "Wrong parameter attribute_code."

It is happened after upgrade Magento to 2.4.3-p1

Comment: try to flush cache and reindex. Then start again.

Comment: I'm getting the same error with Magento ver. 2.4.5